# Explain the meaning of JPA Criteria API From class and its type parameters

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-criteria

What is the purpose of class [javax.persistence.criteria.From](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html) and what do its type parameters `Z` and `X` stand for ?

The documentation is not clear at all.

I became even more confused after I saw that the type [javax.persistence.criteria.Root](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Root.html) has the following definition:

`public interface Root<X> extends From<X,X>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common interface for: `javax.persistence.criteria.Join` and `javax.persistence.criteria.Root` to allow consistency when you call one of the methods:

- `javax.persistence.criteria.Join#getParent`
- `javax.persistence.criteria.From#getCorrelationParent`

Let's try explain using `javax.persistence.criteria.Join#getParent` 
When You call `javax.persistence.criteria.Join#getParent` result can be another Join or Root and a common interface for both is `javax.persistence.criteria.From`

See example:

```
Root<User> user = query.from(User.class);
Join<User, Account> account = user.join(User_.account);
Join<Account, AccountRole> accountRole = account.join(Account_.accountRoles);
```

then

```
From<?, User> root = account.getParent();// here we have Root<User> extends From<User, User>
From<?, Account> join = accountRole.getParent();// here we have Join<User, Account> extends From<User, Account>
```

And as You can see in the above example Z and X stand for a type of left and right side of the join.